# Is there a discord.py command to change a tag on a forum post?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to create a bot command (discord.py v2.0) that allows a moderator to change a forum post's tag.  For example, by using `!complete`, the moderator would change to forums post's tag from "issue" to "completed".  The command would be sent in the post that the user would like to close.

Is this possible with discord.py's current version.  I have not seen any documentation in the Github regarding this.

Comment: I don't understand how Discord has anything to do with "forums". Isn't it a *chat* program?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Discord is not a forum, it's a Q&A knowledgebase :). Jokes aside, discord has recently added "[forum channels](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/6208479917079-Forum-Channels-FAQ)", which work like any other forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible with the stable version of discord.py

The latest version on GitHub currently does [*seem* to support this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=applied_tags#discord.Thread.edit) via the `applied_tags` parameter on the `Thread.edit` method (channels within a Forum are called Thread.)

I'm not 100% sure the best-practice way to create the `ForumTag` class the `applied_tags` parameter wants, so it might just be best to wait until this releases on v2.1, as the code is not guaranteed to stay the same